# Windows CMD Changing Color of One Character

Tags: colors, cmd

Is there a way to change the color of just ONE character in the Windows Command Prompt? I looked for this but only found how to change the whole background and foreground. Is there any way to implement the `Color` command for just one character?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is not a simple command for this, but Carlos created this function to help change character colours.  Run the batch file and it will show you some colour changes.

```
@Echo Off
Call :Color A "######" \n E "" C " 21 " E "!" \n B "######" \n
Pause >Nul
Exit /B

:Color
:: v21
:: Arguments: hexColor text [\n] ...
:: \n -> newline ... -> repeat
:: Supported in windows XP, 7, 8.
:: In XP extended ascii characters are printed as dots.
:: For print quotes, use empty text.
SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
Subst `: "!Temp!" >Nul &`: &Cd \
SetLocal DisableDelayedExpansion
If Not Exist `.7 (
Echo(|(Pause >Nul &Findstr "^" >`)
Set /P "=." >>` <Nul
For /F "delims=;" %%# In (
'"Prompt $H;&For %%_ In (_) Do Rem"') Do (
Set /P "=%%#%%#%%#" <Nul >`.3
Set /P "=%%#%%#%%#%%#%%#" <Nul >`.5
Set /P "=%%#%%#%%#%%#%%#%%#%%#" <Nul >`.7))
:__Color
Set "Text=%~2"
If Not Defined Text (Set Text=^")
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set /P "LF=" <` &Set "LF=!LF:~0,1!"
For %%# in ("!LF!") Do For %%_ In (
\ / :) Do Set "Text=!Text:%%_=%%~#%%_%%~#!"
For /F delims^=^ eol^= %%# in ("!Text!") Do (
If #==#! EndLocal
If \==%%# (Findstr /A:%~1 . \` Nul
Type `.3) Else If /==%%# (Findstr /A:%~1 . /.\` Nul
Type `.5) Else (Echo %%#\..\`>`.dat
Findstr /F:`.dat /A:%~1 .
Type `.7))
If "\n"=="%~3" (Shift
Echo()
Shift
Shift
If ""=="%~1" Goto :Eof
Goto :__Color
```

Comment: That's a lot of code.... There must be a way to make that shorter with no libraries

Comment: You can use a third party executable to generate colour, but native batch has only the `color` command.  Type `help color` in a cmd prompt.

Comment: It works when the parameter is a text string, but it fails when used with a variable containing text. So Sad!

Answer (score 1):

If you use Windows 10, you can alternatively use VT100 sequences to achieve this:
Start your file with setting the ESC character

```
for /f "delims=" %%E in ('forfiles /p "%~dp0." /m "%~nx0" /c "cmd /c echo(0x1B"') do (
    set "ESC=%%E"
)
```

Now you can use this to inline change the color accordingly:

```
echo This is %ESC%[36ma%ESC%[0m single character
```

gives

```
This is a single character
```

while a is blue. You can make convinience macros out of this, like this:

```
set "BLUE=%ESC%[36m"
set "ENDC=%ESC%[0m"
```

and then use them like that:

```
echo This is also %BLUE%a%ENDC% single character
```

Take a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences#span-idtextformattingspanspan-idtextformattingspanspan-idtextformattingspantext-formatting) for more info on VT100