# How can I change the colour of individual chars?

Tags: c#, console-application

I am trying to create wordle in C#. Below is my code for converting the users input into a char array to change the colour of each individual char based on the positioning of the letters

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < userGuessChars2D.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    // Clear and  re-display the board and increase guess number by 1
    Console.Clear();
    displayBoard();
    guessNum++;

    // Store user guess
    userGuesses = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();

    for (int j = 0; j < userGuessChars2D.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        // Check if user input is included in answer and extra word list
        if (answers.Contains(userGuesses) || extras.Contains(userGuesses))
        {
            userGuessChars2D[i, j] = userGuesses[j];

            // Check the positioning of the letters and change the colour accordingly
            if (userGuessChars2D[i, j] == answerChars2D[i, j])
            {
                Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            }
            else if (userGuessChars2D[i, j] != answerChars2D[i, j])
            {
                Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid word");
        }
    }
}
```

No matter what I do, even if I input the correct word, the entire board returns red.

Does anyone know what I can do to fix this?

Comment: Please do all you can to make it as easy as possible for us to help you, which includes making your code as readable as possible. There was no reason at all to have that big wad of leading whitespace in your code. You can select code without the whitespace in the first place in VS by holding down Alt as you select or you can use the editor on this site to remove it one Tab's worth at a time. It just takes a little bit of effort on your part.

Comment: my bad bro i didn't know u could do that

Comment: If you select text and click the code button, it will indent it by four spaces. If you click again, it will remove the indent. If the text is already indented multiple times, just click the code button multiple times to remove the indent four spaces at a time. Simpler to use the Alt key in VS though, to avoid any unnecessary whitespace. Handly feature.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20483517/windows-cmd-changing-color-of-one-character answer your question?

Comment: Okay, I originally missed the point of this question.  So you clearly have a design flaw, but it's hard to make suggestions with so little of the code available.  Where's the code for displayBoard()?  Please read [ask] and post an [MCVE]

Comment: Perhaps you need to move the displayBoard() call down below the if..else blocks?

Comment: I see your problem now. Your "board" is an array user guesses. You need to move the point at which you change the console foreground color into the displayBoard() method. That's about all I can suggest until you post an [MCVE].

Answer (score 0):

From the code provided, it looks like you drawing the board **then** set the colour. You need write to the console after you've set the colour of the console

```cs
// Check the positioning of the letters and change the colour accordingly
if (userGuessChars2D[i, j] == answerChars2D[i, j])
{
    Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
    
    // Write to the console now
    Console.WriteLine(answerChars2D[i, j]);

    // Optionally reset the console colour for future printing
    Console.ResetColor();
}
else if (userGuessChars2D[i, j] != answerChars2D[i, j])
{
    Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
    
    // Write to the console now
    Console.WriteLine(answerChars2D[i, j]);

    // Optionally reset the console colour for future printing
    Console.ResetColor();
}
```

You may want to further refactor this to prevent duplicate logic

```cs
public void Print(string answer, ConsoleColor color)
{
    Console.BackgroundColor = color;
    Console.WriteLine(answer);
    Console.ResetColor();
}

// Use
Print(userGuessChars2d[i, j], ConsoleColor.Green);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [ANSI escape code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code).

OS Windows of the latest versions supports them. [Console Virtual Terminal Sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences).

Their usage looks like this:

```
const string RED = "\x1b[31m";
const string GREEN = "\x1b[32m";
const string UNDERLINE = "\x1B[4m";
const string RESET = "\x1B[0m";

Console.WriteLine(GREEN + "Success!" + RESET);
Console.WriteLine(RED + "Error!" + RESET);
Console.WriteLine("Some " + UNDERLINE + "underlined" + RESET + " text");
Console.WriteLine(RED + "Hello " + GREEN + "World!" + RESET);
```